# MATLAB regular expression denied to remove spaces at beginning of a string

Tags: regex, string, matlab, str-replace

suppose that we have this string in MATLAB:

```
mm = ['  44412 (25.01%)'];
```

I want remove only fist space(s) in this string to have this output:

```
'44412 (25.01%)'
```

I'm using `strrep(mm,'\^\s\s','')` but didn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: I haven't looked at the regex yet but another potential option is [`strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) if you aren't concerned with trailing whitespace. Or maybe [`strjust`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html)

Answer (score 5):

The issue with [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) is that it does not allow you to utilize `regex` patterns. The first part of your filter (`'\^'`) also tries to match `^` explicitly, so it won't work on your string. If you remove the leading `\` your filter works fine with [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), but is limited to strings with exactly 2 leading whitespaces.

Try using this more generic filter instead with `regexprep`.

```
str = '  44412 (25.01%)';
newstr = regexprep(str, '^\s+', '');
```

Which returns:

```
newstr =

44412 (25.01%)
```

What I've done here is match 1 or more whitespace characters at the beginning of the string. This syntax also allows us to use it on strings without any leading whitespace and not have it make any modification.

---

Edit: Here are some built-in alternatives!

You could use [`strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html), but it strips leading *and* trailing whitespace:

```
newstr = strtrim(str);
```

You can also use [`strjust`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html) to left-justify your string:

```
newstr = strjust(str, 'left');
```

If you want to be really creative, you could [flip](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) your array and use [`deblank`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deblank.html), which strips trailing whitespace:

```
newstr = fliplr(deblank(fliplr(str)));
```